# html and node.js script on the same heroku instance

Tags: html, node.js, heroku

I'm trying to get something very simple to work with node.js and im kind of stuck at the moment . Hoping someone could help me out with this problem.. Im trying a very simple node.js application.. Basically there is a index.html file which has a form with name as a parameter.. onclick of the button calls a JQuery script which performs a POST request to a node.js script with the NAME value obtained from the html form..
      Now the post request is made to the node.js script which runs a HTTP server on its default port.. All that the node.js script does is accepts the parameter and replies with a very trivial response which includes the POST parameter which was sent.. This reponse is caught by JQuery and is given to the user using alert..
     So i have index.html and login.js as my two scripts.. Now Im using heroku to host these files.. Problem is once they're uploaded it doesnt really open the html file by default.. it runs the login.js by default..So the HTML is never opened.. Thats probably cause I have a procfile which loads login.js to the dyno.. But if i remove the procfile then i get an error in the logs saying "No web processes running" .. 
     So basically, long story short , is there a way to have an index.html and a node.js file running on the same heroku instance where the html requests the node.js for info and returns it back..
      Here are links to my html and node.js scripts

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/904687/index.html
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/904687/login.js

Comment: don't ignore `node_modules/` or bower_components in `.gitignore` when deploying to heroku

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use Node.js Express.js to serve the html file and then also handle the login route.

The whole thing would look something like.

file : package.json

```
{
  "name" : "LoginPage",
  "version" : "0.0.1",
  "dependencies" : {
    "express" : "3.x"
  },
  "main" : "index.js"
}
```

file : index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var oneDay = 86400000;

app.use(express.compress());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: oneDay }));

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.listen(process.env.PORT);

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  var result = req.rawBody;
  res.send("hello there world data is " + result);
});
```

directory structure

```
package.json
index.js
public
  index.html
```